# Using React form submission in C# .NET Controller class

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

I'm learning how to use React with .NET and am using the Visual Studio templates provided to play around (I'm using a Mac, if that is useful for context). I am starting with very simple back end applications and trying to get my React front end to link to these. I am very new to using React and .NET so I apologise if the questions I ask seem simple. Here is my current issue:

I have the following C# Controller class which retrieves and returns the middle letters of a string:

MiddleLetterController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace TestingReactDotNet.Controllers
{
    public class MiddleLetterController : Controller
    {
        public string GetMiddle(string word)
        {
           if (word.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
                return word.Substring(word.Length / 2 - 1, 2); 
            }
           else
            {
                return word.Substring(word.Length / 2, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using React on the front end and want whatever the user types and submits in the form to be the `word` passed as an argument to the `GetMiddle()` method and for this to be displayed on screen.

My current MiddleLetter.js file is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class MiddleLetter extends Component {

    state = {
      word: "",
    };

    updateInput(key, value) {
    // update react state
    this.setState({
      [key]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <center>
        <div className="App">
          <div>
            Type a word...
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type word here ..."
              value={this.state.word}
              onChange={e => this.updateInput("word", e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={() => ?????)}>Submit</button>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
    );
  }
}
```

I have looked at the React documentation but cannot work out how / the best way to link the React form submission to the backend application. I would be really grateful if anyone had any suggestions please :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to pull in a library like axios or fetch into your react project "yarn add axios" in your react folder.

Then at the top of your MiddleLetter.js you'll need to `import axios from axios;`

create an instance of axios in MiddleLetter.js, something like:

```
const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: "localhost:{whatever port you're running on}",
)}
```

Then in your "updateInput" function where your comments are add:

`const response = await instance.get("/middleletter/" + value);`

your response should have the return value from the controller.

Then for your controller.

add `[HttpGet({word})]`
over `public string GetMiddle(string word)`

This will let the controller get the word from your URL.

There are better ways to do all of this. But this should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @bmccoy04 ! Much appreciated. Just wondering - when you say "there are better ways to do all of this", what sort of things were you thinking of? You don't need to go into detail, just suggestions that I can look into would be appreciated?

Comment: 1. You probably don't want to put your axios config/creation in your MiddleLetter.js file.  You can make an api.js file that exposes "Get" and you pass it some params.  That way other js files can just use that instance with having to keep creating them.

2. Your controller is going to grow and others will be added.  There are things like taking that logic out of the controller and use dependency injection to "inject" a separate class that does the logic.  That way you separate your concerns.

As the project grows you're going to want to create more reusable classes/components.

Comment: Thanks @bmccoy04 that is really helpful. 

I have tried to implement the method you suggested but cannot see where to put ` [HttpGet({word})]` without receiving errors telling me 'the name word does not exist in this current context'

Comment: Sorry, the edit must have messed it up.  It should be [HttpGet({"word"})].   Word should be a string.